# Isn't $\bigcap_{i=1}^5 A_i=A_5$ where $A_i=\{x \mid x \in \mathbb{N},0 \le x \le \frac{1}{n}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A_i=\{x \mid x \in \mathbb{N},0 \le x \le \frac{1}{n}\}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. which one is correct?(Note that $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$)

> 1.$\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i=A_1$
>
> 2.$\bigcap_{i=1}^5 A_i=A_5$
>
> 3.$\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i=\{0\}$
>
> 4.All three are correct.

It is easy to say that the first one is correct.Also the book gave the answer $1$.Also It is easy to say $3$ is wrong.But what about $2$ isn't it correct?I think it is correct because $\bigcap_{i=1}^5 A_i=\varnothing$ and also $A_5=\varnothing$.What's your idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean $A_i=\{x\in\mathbb{N}: 0\leqslant x\leqslant\frac{1}{i}\}$, otherwise your definition makes no sence. If so, then $A_i=\{0\}$ for $i\geqslant 2$, and $A_1=\{0,1\}$. Using this, it follows easily that 1 is false for $n\neq 1$, while (2) and (3) are true. Interestingly, this is also true if we replace the $x\in\mathbb{N}$ by $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ or $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

EDIT: I didn't notice $0\notin\mathbb{N}$ for this question. In that case we find that $A_i=\emptyset$ for $i\geqslant 2$, and $A_1=\{1\}$. So only (2) is true.

EDIT 2: Now (1) has edited from $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i=A_i$ into $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i=A_1$, this is correct as well.

Comment: I told that zero isn't a natural number.

Comment: note that I am not who give downvote.

Comment: Fixed it now. Always very confusing when $0$ is left out.

Comment: Excuse me I wrote the first one wrong.Now I think both is correct.